# Why does Worksheet.Hyperlink.Range sometimes return a series of ranges as opposed to just one when iterating through the Worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which iterates through all of the Hyperlinks on all Worksheets in a Workbook, and if a Hyperlink's range is equal to a previously specified range, copies the Hyperlink to the same range on a destination sheet in a new Workbook and then moves onto the next Worksheet. This works flawlessly through the course of about 5 Worksheets, then suddenly throws a mismatch error and the whole process fails.

While debugging I've determined that every time, at the same Hyperlink on the same Worksheet, `Worksheet.Hyperlink.Range` (`hyperlink.range` in my code) returns a series of ranges rather than just one (as far as I can tell), and since the loop compares this to a single range, this is where the mismatch is occurring. The problem is that I can not determine why this is happening. I can not find any difference in the properties of this Hyperlink compared to the others that would cause it to be expressed as a series of ranges.

```
    Public Sub CopyLink(fromRange As range, toRange As range)

        Dim hyperlink As Hyperlink
        Dim fromSheet As Worksheet
        Set fromSheet = fromRange.Worksheet

        For Each hyperlink In fromSheet.Hyperlinks
            If hyperlink.range = fromRange Then 'mismatch happens here after several successful iterations
                hyperlink.range.Copy
                toRange.PasteSpecial
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

I would like to figure out how to either

A. alter the comparison of the two ranges in such a way that avoids this issue

or

B. understand the cause of the issue so that I can hopefully rectify it.

Comment: Could you compare the range.address to avoid the error?

Comment: That's a good thought. I'll look into this now and report back.

Comment: Update: range.address returns several cells, coinciding with the range returning multiple ranges. This would absolutely work if this wasn't the case and I appreciate the idea. However I'm still unsure why this particular hyperlink.range is returning a series of cells as opposed to just the one being iterated over.

Comment: Are the cells contiguous, can you comment the address?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "if a Hyperlink's range is equal to a previously specified range"?  Do you mean that they refer to the same address/location? Or that they contain the same underlying value?

Comment: Hyperlinks can refer to a contiguous range of cells, e.g., "A1:H16", etc. So, either you need to alter your existing hyperlinks, or control for that possibility.

Comment: @NathanSutherland Yes they are contiguous. The address returned is $D$D:$D$36

Comment: @JvdV As far as I can tell there are no merged cells on that hyperlink. Is there a specific way you would recommend determining this other than looking at the cell?

Comment: @DavidZemens The macro is given two ranges: the source range and the destination range. For the given sheet the macro iterates through all hyperlinks and compares the range of the current hyperlink to the source range. If they are equal the range is copied. The macro compares the actual range of the hyperlink to the range received by the macro. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: `$D$D:$D$36` isn't a valid address?

Comment: Apologies. It was a typo. the address is $D$6:$D$36

Comment: No, you still haven't explained what you mean by "equal". Do you mean the same underlying *value*? Or do you mean the same *location*?

Comment: From what you are saying, Nathan's original suggestion should work.

Comment: @DavidZemens Sorry, it is comparing the location of the hyperlink. I've been doing this by testing the equality of the ranges themselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fromRange` is always a single cell range, and the `hyperlink.Range` may refer to multiple cells. The mismatch here is with your comparison:

```
if hyperlink.range = fromRange
```

When a `Range` represents a single cell, it will evaluate to its `Value` property by default (the actual implementation is a little more complicated), and this will return the underlying data (string, numeric, date, etc.). When a `Range` represents multiple cells, its `Value` is an *array* of the individual cell values.

So you can expect a mismatch as a result because you have an array on the left side, and something else on the right. The `=` comparison operator can't handle an array on either side. Try it:

```
If Range("A1:B1") = Range("C1:D1") Then
```

The above will also raise a mismatch error, even though both sides of the `=` are arrays of the same size!

You may want to consider comparing the `Address` property instead?

```
hyperlink.range.Address = fromRange.Address
```

Or

```
' tests the top/left cell
hyperlink.range(1,1).Address = fromRange.Address
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I understand that this is what is causing the error, the problem is that I cannot understand why the hyperlink is referring to multiple cells in this particular instance, since it is the same hyperlink as several of the previous ones that were iterated through. There is nothing about this particular use of the hyperlink that should change the range referred to and this is what I would like to determine. I've also attempted to compare the hyperlink.range.address but this is given as a series of cells as I explained in the comments above.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the second option you suggested. I will give that a try and report back.

Comment: The answer to the question "Why does a hyperlink refer to multiple cells?" Is: "because that's how it was created". You say you've attempted to compare the addresses, but you don't say what happens when you do this. Of course they will not be equivalent. So what do you want to do in that case?

Answer (score 4):

If you select multiple cells an then add a hyperlink, you only get one link displayed, but all of the selected cells respond as if they are hyperlinked.

The `hyperlink.Range.Address` property here is `$B$2:$B$15`

[image]